# Change the date format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've a set of dates to be converted into a specified format in excel. Can someone help me with this.

Eg:

`21/08/2021` converted to `Aug_WE21`

Formula tried :

```
=Text(21/08/2021,"mmm"&"_WE"&dd)
```

It is showing `#NAME?` Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date will need to be in Quotes and the full line of the format should also be in quotes with `\` to escape the added text:

```
=TEXT("21/08/2021","mmm\_\W\Edd")
```